# I have schema extension on the user object in azure active directory. How can I make the claims return this data?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to add schema extensions on the user object. Referred this source : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups

I know I can view the extension values using the endpoint, e.g. GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=graphlearn_courses/courseId eq ‘123’&$select=displayName,id,description,graphlearn_courses

Is there a way I can get the extension values with the claims returned on authenticating a user?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC or Web API?

Comment: I am using Web API, server side. I would like to access the claims in my code behind file (aspx.vb) for the Login.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported. I created a [uservoice idea](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32757895-user-schema-extension-properties-can-be-configured) for this - please feel free to vote on it.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read about customizing claims but the documentation is not very good, so was wondering if it was possible to do it that way...but maybe not.